# Using Active Directory roles while accessing a website from JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In our company the web app that we are testing uses the active directory roles assigned to the user for accessing the website.

**Edit:** 
Important information that I forgot to mention is that, while accessing the website I am not prompted for the username and password. The website is only displayed if I have the correct Active Directory role assigned to my user profile.

For Example,

1. Opening IE as myself - able to access the website.
2. Opening IE as a service account (with required Active Directory roles) - able to access the website.
3. Opening IE as a different user outside my project - not able to access the website.

I have tried (skeptically, desperate to get it working) Basic/ Kerberos Authorization in the HTTP Authorization Manager and even running JMeter as that service account still no luck. I keep getting the below

```
Thread Name: Users 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-04-26 17:08:18 CDT
Load time: 83
Connect Time: 13
Latency: 83
Size in bytes: 438
Sent bytes:136
Headers size in bytes: 243
Body size in bytes: 195
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 22:08:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 195
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html
DataEncoding: null
```

I am just trying to find out if any one here has got the JMeter working in a similar scenario/ if any one can point me in the right direction to overcome this hurdle.

Thanks all for your help in advance.

[image: HTTP Authorization Manager Conf]

Comment: Please add `HTTP Authorization Manager` to your request. For more details, please refer https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter and http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager

Comment: Thanks @NaveenKumarNamachivayam, I am already using HTTP Authorization Manager but without luck.

Comment: Does the other user has access to that website? Check with your sys admin or developer who maintains the LDAP. The `other` users must be present in the org. Else, you will get 401 error.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam I am assuming you mean other users who are not working in my project, so the answer to that is no, when a new member comes to our team an active directory role is added to the user profile by the helpdesk so they can access the website developed by our project.

Comment: As you mentioned in the point #3.

Comment: Yes, mentioned in the point #3 are the people not in my project. They will not be able to access the website they will simply get "401 Authorization Required" which is what I am getting when I am using JMeter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142841/discussion-between-naveenkumar-namachivayam-and-venkat-rao).

Comment: Please post the HTTP Authorization Manager configuration snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the exact implementation of the authentication in your application.

Given you receive `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` - this is definitely not Basic HTTP Auth.

`Negotiate` may stand either for [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or for [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) (or in some cases for both, i.e. if Kerberos is not successful it will fall back to NTLM) and JMeter needs to be configured differently for these schemes.

For example for NTLM you need to provide only credentials and domain in the [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and for Kerberos you need to populate Realm and set your Kerberos settings ([KDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_distribution_center) and login config) under *jaas.conf* and *krb5.conf* files

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more information and example configurations.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this and get back.